# Plotting two or more lines on a graph using loops

Tags: r, loops, dynamic, nested, graphing

I am trying to plot two or more lines on the same graph using a loop. My plot is a population dynamic in which I want to repeatedly change the value of the starting population but keep all other parameters the same. I want to plot the different outcomes on one graph. Can anyone help?

Comment: No pictures of code are useful here. Use text.

Comment: `MAX.Y` is not defined.

Comment: Now you want to specify what should be happening.  Do you wnat to set MAX.Y at 50000?

Comment: MAX.Y is maximum years which I want to remain at 30, i am trying to change the lp or sp variables so that the starting population varies

Comment: What do you see with `plot(lp~year, xlab="Time (years)",ylim=c(0, MAX.Y) )`

Comment: still the same one graph

Comment: You need to provide code that works. What is the value of `year` object in your code? Please update your code with `MAX.Y`, `year` and any other missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
MAX.Y<-30
# year<-0:30
year<-1:30
rlp<-0.1
lp<-rep(0,MAX.Y)
lp[1]<-4000
K<-4000000
for(n in 1: (MAX.Y-1)) {lp[n+1]<-lp[n]+(rlp)*(1-lp[n]/K)*lp[n]}
# plot(lp~year, xlab="Time (years)", ylab="Population size", main=c(paste("B)   Anchovy population growth"), paste ("in less productive environment")), col="darkorchid", type="l", cex.main=1.0)
sp<-rep(0,MAX.Y)
sp[1]<-100000
for(n in 1: (MAX.Y-1)) {sp[n+1]<-sp[n]+(rlp)*(1-sp[n]/K)*sp[n]}
# lines(sp~year, type="l", col="black")

data = data.frame(year=year,lp=lp, sp=sp)
data = reshape2::melt(data, id.vars = 'year')
ggplot(data, aes(year, value, colour = variable))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(x = "Time (years)", y = "Population size", 
       title = "B)   Anchovy population growth \n in less productive environment")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.
First, since the computations for `lp` and `sp` are the same, only the initial values change, create a function to do it.

```
f <- function(initial, MAX, rlp, K){
  x <- numeric(MAX)
  x[1] <- initial
  for(i in seq_len(MAX - 1)) {
    x[i + 1] <- x[i] + rlp*(1 - x[i]/K)*x[i]
  }
  x
}
```

Now `sapply` the function to a vector of initial values.

```
MAX.Y <- 30
rlp <- 0.1
year <- seq_len(MAX.Y)
K <- 4000000

InitialValues <- setNames(c(4000, 100000), c("lp", "sp"))
x <- sapply(InitialValues, f, MAX.Y, rlp, K)
```

And plot it with `matlines`. But for `matlines` to work the plot must be created with the custom title, axis limits, etc.

```
plot(1, type = "n", 
     xlim = range(year), ylim = range(x),
     main = c(paste("B)   Anchovy population growth"), paste ("in less productive environment")),
     xlab = "Time (years)", 
     ylab = "Population size", 
     cex.main = 1.0,
     col = c("darkorchid", "black"))
matlines(x, lty = "solid")
```

[image]

Comment: could you possibly explain what the first function part of the code (step one) is actually doing?

Comment: @AlisonSmith It's creating a numeric vector of length `MAX`, one of the function's arguments. It then assigns `initial` to the vector's first element. Try `numeric(3)` and `character(3)` and see the results.